# import javascipt jquery file in to react file

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I downloaded a html template from the internet and want to use it in my react-app

here is the website I used -> https://html5up.net/dimension

the directory include css and js file

but when I directly import the js file like this

```
import './assets/js/main.js'
```

the error comes out

```
Failed to compile.

./assets/js/util.js
 Line 10:4:   '$a' is not defined                                                    no-undef
 Line 10:4:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
 Line 11:4:   'b' is not defined                                                     no-undef
 Line 13:3:   '$a' is not defined                                                    no-undef
 Line 20:4:   'b' is not defined                                                     no-undef
 Line 33:10:  'b' is not defined                                                     no-undef
 Line 587:4:  'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef
```

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

at first I thought it was a jquery problem

so I download the jquery with npm

```
npm i jquery
```

and type following line at the top of js file

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

but the problem still there

is there any methods that I can import jquery file into the react?

here is a part of code in util.js

```
(function($) {

/**
 * Generate an indented list of links from a nav. Meant for use with panel().
 * @return {jQuery} jQuery object.
 */
$.fn.navList = function() {

    var $this = $(this);
        $a = $this.find('a'),
        b = [];

    $a.each(function() {

        var $this = $(this),
            indent = Math.max(0, $this.parents('li').length - 1),
            href = $this.attr('href'),
            target = $this.attr('target');

        b.push(
            '<a ' +
                'class="link depth-' + indent + '"' +
                ( (typeof target !== 'undefined' && target != '') ? ' target="' + target + '"' : '') +
                ( (typeof href !== 'undefined' && href != '') ? ' href="' + href + '"' : '') +
            '>' +
                '<span class="indent-' + indent + '"></span>' +
                $this.text() +
            '</a>'
        );

    });

    return b.join('');

};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `import $ from 'jquery'` in ./assets/js/util.js

Comment: I tried 
I tried import in util.js and my react file
neither can work...

Comment: the error is that there are some variables not defined, check your variables in util.js

Comment: I add a part of util file

Comment: `var $this = $(this);` is wrong the correct is `var $this = $(this),`

Answer (score 0):

summary first: that util.js didn't passed the eslint because it's using deprecated syntax.

let's see what's exactly in the util.js:

```
// line 9-11:
var $this = $(this);
$a = $this.find('a'),
b = [];
```

as you can see `$a` was assigned but not declared. that's intolerable for eslint. so it says: `'$a' is not defined`.

also, line 10 end up with a `,` but a `;` was expected.

then, in line 11, `b` was assigned but also net declared.

other issues are just like whats going on above.

Comment: So you mean I should put var in front of each variable ?
and change some of , into ;?